# How do I make the child div have a large width than its parent element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

How do I make the child div have a large width than its parent element?

**ANSWER**

```
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **bottom** instead **margin-bottom** this will put your image to 50px of distance starting in the bottom of the page or the parent element whit relative position. Note that **bottom** can be used whit **absolute** or **fixed** positionng

Comment: Ok. So put position: absoulte on the parent element, and position: relative; bottom: 50px on the child. This works, but how do I get that child element to span across the full viewport, without taking the width of the container that it is in?

Comment: Oh! I figured it out. **position: relative;  width: 100vw; left: calc(-50vw + 50%); bottom: 50px;**